# Is there a way to do inheritance or code reuse in an AWS CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-code-deploy

I'm building a CloudFormation template that includes an `AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration` and an `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup` that uses that LaunchConfiguration. For my stack I'm going to need multiple AutoScalingGroups, but I want them in separate security groups.

I'm also going to be using CodeDeploy, so my LaunchConfiguration includes the Metadata and UserData properties to install and run the CodeDeploy agent (as shown in line 262 of http://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-codedeploy-us-east-1/templates/latest/CodeDeploy_SampleCF_Template.json). Because I have to specify the security group in the LaunchConfiguration instead of in the AutoScalingGroup, I have to have multiple copies of the LaunchConfiguration in my template with only a single-line difference.

Is there a way to reduce the number of times the lengthy Metadata and UserData sections will appear in my template? I tried creating a mapping, but they only allow alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write code to create your template JSON instead of writing it manually - then you can use whatever abstractions are available in your language of choice to create the different LaunchConfiguration resources.

Languages that let you represent maps and vectors as literals are considerably better suited for this than those who don't.

For instance, the Clojure literal

```
{"Type" "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"
 "Properties" {"KeyName" {"Ref" "KeyName"}
               "ImageId" {"Ref" "AMI"}}}
```

can automatically be translated into the JSON string

```
{"Type":"AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration",
 "Properties":{"ImageId":{"Ref":"AMI"},
               "KeyName":{"Ref":"KeyName"}}}
```

(Though in practice you would only create the JSON for the full template, not individual resources.)

You can then do things like

```
(defn launch-configuration
  [ami]
  {"Type" "AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration"
   "Properties" {"KeyName" {"Ref" "KeyName"}
                 "ImageId" ami}})
```

and

```
(map launch-configuration ["ami1" "ami2" "ami3"])
```

to create multiple similar resources.

Handcrafting the template JSON is really only convenient for very small templates.

Answer (score 1):

I found out about CDK recently. Haven't used it yet but it appears to be a better way than writing out all the template code directly. Resources can be defined using TypeScript, JavaScript, Java, and C# and compiled to produce CloudFormation templates. An example of a Stack being created in Java:

```
public class MyStack extends Stack {
    public MyStack(final App scopy, final String id) {
        this(scope, id, null);
    }

    public MyStack(final App scope, final String id, final StackProps props) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        new Bucket(this, "MyFirstBucket", BucketProps.builder()
            .withVersioned(true)
            .build());
    }
}
```

More on CDK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/CDK/latest/userguide/what-is.html